# how to add textfield data into another page in tableview cell

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm newbie to Objective C...i want to show textfield data into table view. I tried it creating another UIViewController class but I don't know how to do it. for ex. I have two XIB view now first XIB include a text field and a button. now I want to display textfield text into 2nd XIB in table view.

Comment: What is "another page in table view".  I wasn't aware table views had pages.

Comment: i mean there are two viewController one include textfield and a pass data value button and other viewController include table.then how to show data which I entered in my textfield into tableview.

Comment: All data should be in a custom model class (unless it's trivial) which should be *passed around* (like a bong) to each view controller (which are the teenagers in my analogy).

Comment: can't understand what you are saying..please explain in brief.

Comment: It seems that you need to pass data between view controllers hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: hey can u provide me whole code?